# MongoDB aggregate and group for different key names

Tags: mongodb

This is my first post here, and really looking a help.

I went to find [MongoDB aggregate result with two different keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30241736/mongodb-aggregate-result-with-two-different-keys)
but the relevency of the same could not be obtained. Or rather I might have not been able to comply with the solution

The problem is I have a collection in which documents have different keys. Based on that key the resultant data would be obtained as an array of objects.
Below is the collection structure

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("58ec840e2573065a1e076db3"),
"uniqueid" : "24050951",
"productid" : "5149-1550DM-11",
"record_id" : 1
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("58ec840e2573065a1e076db4"),
"task" : 1,
"record_id" : 1,
"judgement" : {
    "2" : "Functional"
}
}


{
"_id" : ObjectId("58ec840e2573065a1e076db5"),
"qc" : 1,
"record_id" : 1,
"judgement" : {
    "2" : "No Style"
}
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("58ec840e2573065a1e076db6"),
"task" : 2,
"record_id" : 1,
"judgement" : {
    "2" : "Functional"
}
}

{
"_id" : ObjectId("58ec840e2573065a1e076db6"),
"task" : 2,
"record_id" : 2,
"judgement" : {
    "2" : "Functional"
}
}
```

The output I am expecting is an object of three arrays

```
"task"-> Array(3)-> contains three records for record_id 1 and 2 and also one more for task 1 and 2 for record_id 1
"qc" -> Array(1)
"other" -> if the task or qc doesnot exist.
```

It is easy to fetch that as a mongo function where you can write javascript code. But using aggregate it is bit more complex as far as I am concerned.
Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: This is not an aggregation then...

Comment: What is your mongodb server version ?

Comment: @Veeram using 3.4

Comment: what's the status of the question? an answer was given but not accepted or comment placed under it, if it did not work. If it solved it, consider accepting the answer in order to mark the question as solved @Neo

Comment: @Fred-ii- Sorry for the delayed response. Was caught up. Anyways it did not solve the issue

Comment: @Neo It is best to post a comment under a given answer and to tell them what they posted did not work. They don't know if it worked or not ;-) if the question is not worth pursuing or you found your own solution, you can either post your own answer or delete the question; the choice is yours.

Comment: @Fred-ii- New here...just catching up.. Thanks for bringing this up..I will comply with that in future posts of mine

Comment: @Neo welcome, *cheers*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `$facet` with `$match` checking presence (`$exist`) of fields.

```
db.collection.aggregate( [
  {
    $facet: {
      "task": [
           { $match: { task: { $exists: 1 } } }
      ],
      "qc": [
           { $match: { qc: { $exists: 1 } } },
      ],
      "other": [
          { $match: {task: { $exists: 0 } , qc: { $exists: 0 } } },
      ]
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

here you go!

```
db.data.aggregate([
    {$group:{_id:null, task:{$push:"$task"}, qc:{$push:"$qc"}, other:{$pushAll:['$record_id','$judgement']} }}
])
```

**NOTE:** In order to get all fields other than task and qc put those keys in the other $pushAll array as indicated

Comment: @nurulnabi...sorry bro It did not worked as expected. Thanks for the response though

Comment: can you tell, what is the output of the above query and what should be? I mean I not getting where is the problem. May be I can correct?